# Wifi repeater Android app to Linux PC

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, android, kubuntu

The goal is to share the wifi connection from a android device to the linux computer by wifi access point without using mobile data(e.g 4G/3G).

Wifi is activated in Android.

"Share Internet connection" is enabled in the application [Netshare-no-root-tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en).

The [linux machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3evF.png) is connected to the wifi access point provided and http proxy is set as we can see.

Still no internet connection,i tried to ping from the linux system but it fails.

Comment: So for "*share the wifi connection from a android device to the linux computer by wifi access point without using mobile data*" if the Droid connected to wi-fi as well for it's Internet or what? Are you just trying to have the Droid device on the same network as the Linux device so those two can talk to each other and not just so the Linux OS can use the Droid's Internet connection (i.e. 3G, etc.)?

Comment: The question belongs to the user "[netshare](https://superuser.com/users/760837/netshare)" and there's an edit attempt from the user "[netshare2](https://superuser.com/users/760942/netshare2)". This may be helpful: *[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)*

Comment: Allow that port on firewall (`8282`)

Answer (score 0):

if you can ping android from pc then check if you can ping main router too(wifi access point).
if you can't then,
check for gateway,dns in linux pc..
 also check for routing table in linux pc

```
ip route
```

also check for routing table in android.

see the output of `iptable -L` on android
if FORWARD policy is set to DROP  then
enable port forwarding on android

you must have rooted android to  do this...